# NodeJS requiring modules not working

Tags: node.js

Im setting up passportjs for my project. I import the passport configuaration file to app.js using the passportConfig variable. I want the passportConfig file to be run in app.js.

```
// app.js file

var mysql          = require('mysql'),
    passport       = require('passport'),
    passportConfig = require('./passportConfig.js');

// Database
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'test'
});
```

>

Right here I don't understand why I need to require mysql and passport again. Because I already did it in app.js. When I remove the requires an error comes up telling me to include them.

```
// passport config file

// Require
var mysql         = require('mysql');
var passport      = require('passport'),


// Database
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'test'
});


module.exports = function(passport) {
    // Passport Session - persistent login sessions
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });


    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        var query = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?';
        var inserts = [id];
        query = mysql.format(query, inserts)...
```

Does this mean that the passportConfig file is not being run in the app.js even though I required the file in my app.js?  This is the only reason I can think of

Comment: Just a guess, maybe define mysql and passport a line above the config. Maybe defining them all with the same statement is causing the issue. I'm probably wrong, but I can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you "require" a module. Node.js does wrapping of each module. What is wrapping:

> Wrapping: To give the file its private scope. This is what makes both the `require` and `module` objects local to every file we require.

[source](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8)

That is why I think you need to include `passport` and `mysql` in both files.